# Dragger View is not Injecting

Tags: android, dagger

I've imported the [Draggable Panel](https://github.com/pedrovgs/DraggablePanel) sample and lib. I am using plain eclipse and ADT I've set up the libs and build path and library projects. Project structure looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YFPa.jpg)
Also I set up the factory path for the annotation processing.
[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rpnD1.jpg) is the image.

```
<factorypath>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="/MainActivity/libs/dagger-compiler-1.2.1.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="/MainActivity/libs/javawriter-2.5.0.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="/MainActivity/libs/dagger-1.2.1.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
    <factorypathentry kind="WKSPJAR" id="/MainActivity/libs/javax.inject-1.jar" enabled="true" runInBatchMode="false"/>
</factorypath>
```

The projects compile fine, but the view are not injecting or initialized. for example the below code does not work.

```
@OnClick(R.id.iv_places)
void openSimpleSampleActivity() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, PlacesSampleActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: any errors in LogCat ?

Comment: try to replace `(this)` with activity `context` inside the intent , coz `this` is belong to the view not to the activity i guess

Comment: No It just does not work. If I use `onClickListener` then the view is responding. I am getting null pointer wherever the sample is using injection. for example If I use @InjectView( R.id.lv) , the listview is null.

Comment: can u post the Logcat once u drag the view ?

Comment: The method `openSimpleSampleActivity` is not being called.

Comment: i think u need `onTouch` to execute `openSimpleSampleActivity`

Comment: On Click is not working It just show the Home screen. I can't click further. http://imgur.com/oxiOWOR

Comment: But onClick annotation should work.

Comment: just try `ontouch` you are touching the view not clicking it